# Approximation theory and proximinal sets

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation-theory

The question is to give an example such that the finite union of proximinal sets is not proximinal.

I have no idea to construct any example to suit this problem, will anybody help me?

Comment: What is a proximinal set? I found no simple definition on wikipedia...

Comment: E is proximinal set in X if for any point x there exist e in E such that infimum( over e in E) norm (x-e)= norm x-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such example. Suppose $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are proximinal subsets of a normed space $X$, and $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. Let $x\in X$. For every $i$, pick $a_i\in A_i$ such that $\inf_{a\in A_i}\|x-a\| =\|x-a_i\|$. Among the points $a_i$, choose one that minimizes $\|x-a_i\|$. This point attains the minimum of $\|x-a\|$ over all $a\in A$.

Same works in metric spaces, actually.

It is true that the *uniqueness* of nearest point is not preserved under finite unions. That is, a finite union of Chebyshev sets is usually not Chebyshev. E.g., the union of two one-point sets.